# Azure B2C - 2 Applications, Different Protocols

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have 2 applications. The first is a portal that loads reports from the second in an iFrame. I'll refer to both as Portal App and iFrame App respectively.

Portal App uses Oauth2 authz code grant flow. iFrame app uses SAML2.

I have implemented custom policies for both by means of 2 different relying party files within the same B2C tenant.

There is a need to not have user authenticate 2ce - one for Portal App, a second time for iFrame app. But then of course the Technical Profiles speak different protocols (OpenIdConenct and SAML2) so that token and claims will be different.

Question: Is it possible to achieve a single authentication for both applications?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, if the iframe app is going to use SSO, this should just work, no config necessary as it will use the single sign on cookies that AAD B2C has set from the Portal App logon. The key will be that the SAML flow uses redirects entirely throughout the interaction with AAD B2C service, **without any user interaction**.

This is because AAD B2C & AAD do not allow rendering of their pages within an iframe. All HTTP 200 responses will come back with X Frame Options deny header from AAD B2C to the browser.

And if the user had logged in with any federated IdP (eg ADFS federated to AAD B2C), that IdP must also not prompt the user in the iframe. If it is a federated SAML IdP, it needs to use the REDIRECT binding.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jas Suri 
So it won't matter that the previous auth to the Portal App used Oauth2 and not SAML? How will iFrame app be able to get the claims it needs?

Comment: Yep, you can get cross protocol SSO. Essentially all new claims are calculated server side during the SSO happening in the iframe.

Comment: Okay, I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Hey @Jas Suri, when you say _The key will be that the SAML flow uses redirects entirely throughout the interaction with AAD B2C service, without any user interaction._ . Is this effected from he SP side? If so,how do I tell them to ensure this? And if it is effected instead on B2C, how do I do same?

Comment: SAML SP side won’t need to do anything specific, other than load their page in the iframe as normal and send the user to the B2C endpoint with a SAML request (forceAuthN false). AAD B2C won’t need any config as the SSO requirements here are out of the box.

Comment: Hey @Jas, went forward with this and now get the x frame options deny header with the 200 responses.Not sure how to validate that the SAML flow uses redirect binding from the application side. The application in question is Microstrategy. Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Reverting acceptance of the answer. Will appreciate some more help on this.

Comment: Take a network trace and make sure the x-cpim-SSO cookie is loaded in the iframe. Also try opening the SAML app in another Tab to see if you get SSO.

Comment: Hey Jas, yes the SAML app loads in a diffeent tab ad after that, the iFrame populates. Should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Sounds like the cookies are not loaded into the iframe, until you went via another tab. Did you do a login to the main app before opening the iframe app?

Comment: Yes, a login to the main app before the loading the tab with the iframe.